# Update a rather large if statement of values to be an array

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of JavaScript code that is rather large and clunky. I would like to take all of the `setValue()` code values and place it all into an array. At this point it seems as though I should just be able to take the values and place them into an array but I feel like I am skipping a step. Thanks for your help.

```js
if (VS_group == "group") {
                                setValue('CORNER_1A_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_111_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_112_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_113_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_114_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_115_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_116_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_117_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_118_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_119_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_120_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('CORNER_1C_COUNT',"S06");
                                setValue('CORNER_1A',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_111',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_112',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_113',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_114',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_115',"WHT");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_116',"WHT");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_117',"BLU");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_118',"BLU");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_119',"BLU");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_120',"BLU");       
                                setValue('CORNER_1C',"BLU");
                                setValue('ALLEY_1D_COUNT',"S06");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    setValue('ALLEY_1P_COUNT',"S06");
                                setValue('ALLEY_1D',"WHT");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          setValue('ALLEY_1P',"WHT");
                                setValue('CORNER_1B_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_131_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_132_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_133_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_134_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_135_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_136_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_137_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_138_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_139_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('INBOARD_140_COUNT',"S06"); 
                                setValue('CORNER_1D_COUNT',"S06");
                                setValue('CORNER_1B',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_131',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_132',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_133',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_134',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_135',"RED");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_136',"BLU");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_137',"BLU");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_138',"BLU");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_139',"BLU");       
                                setValue('INBOARD_140',"BLU");       
                                setValue('CORNER_1D',"BLU");
                            }
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? What exactly does `setValue()` do? Looks more like a key-value-pair like object than an array.

Comment: It's fairly straight forward to do something like `['string1', 'string2', ...].forEach(it => setValue(it, 'S06'))` if you want to reduce the number of times you type out the steps.

Comment: Dont see how a `forEach()`helps since the keys seem different on each line. Also the code seems long but is good for readability and maintenance. Atleast people that know the function `setValue()` can see quickly what is going on.

Comment: I agree with @JavaScript, but if you really want to do this you could use the following syntax: `[ ['key1', 'val1'], ['key2', 'val2'] ].forEach(([key, value] => setValue(key, value))`

Answer (score 1):

You can store these values in an array and apply a loop on that array something like that

```js
[ ['INBOARD_140_COUNT', 'S06'], ['INBOARD_141_COUNT', 'S07'] ].forEach(([key, value] => setValue(key, value));
```

When you run code snippet on StackOverflow it will give an error because "setValue()" is not defined, I wrote this just for better understanding